# How to make this code more professional look?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Coid INT
DECLARE @DTRID INT
DECLARE @EMPID INT
DECLARE @DATE datetime

SELECT TOP 1 @EMPID = tblEmployees.Id, @Coid = tblEmployees.CompanyId, @DATE = tblDailyTimeRecord.TimeIn, @DTRID = tblDailyTimeRecord.Id   FROM tblEmployees INNER JOIN tblDailyTimeRecord ON tblEmployees.Id = tblDailyTimeRecord.EmployeeId WHERE tblDailyTimeRecord.Date = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND tblDailyTimeRecord.TimeOut IS NULL ORDER BY tblDailyTimeRecord.ID DESC
IF @Coid IS NULL
BEGIN
DECLARE @IdentityValue TABLE ( ContactID int,EmpId int,DATE datetime)
INSERT INTO [tblDailyTimeRecord]([EmployeeId],[Date],[TimeOut],[IsModified],[CompanyId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id,INSERTED.EmployeeId,INSERTED.TimeOut INTO @IdentityValue
Select Id,CONVERT(date, GETDATE()),GETDATE(),0,CompanyId From tblEmployees Where AccessCode = 'GI0056'
INSERT INTO tblTimeLog([EmployeeId],[Time],[Type],[TimeLogSourceId],[CreationDate])
Select EmpId,DATE,2,11,GETDATE() From @IdentityValue
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PAIR int
    DECLARE @TIMEOUT datetime
    SET @TIMEOUT = GETDATE()
    IF @DATE IS NULL
        SET @PAIR = 0
    ELSE
        SET @PAIR = 1

    UPDATE [tblDailyTimeRecord] SET TimeOut = @TIMEOUT, PairNo = @PAIR WHERE ID = @DTRID
    INSERT INTO tblTimeLog([EmployeeId],[Time],[Type],[TimeLogSourceId],[CreationDate])
    VALUES (@EMPID,@TIMEOUT,2,11,@TIMEOUT)
END
```

Comment: @Arulkumar I am voting to close this question as unclear because it is not explaining anything about what the code does and would be closed and downvoted on Code Review.

Comment: More whitespace will make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Just general formatting rules:
1. All declaration better are in the beginning.
2. Be consistent: all reserved words in capital
3. Do not use reserved words for column names.
4. Comment your code.
5. Use unified intends.
6. Finish statements with semicolon.
7. If you can, use `CASE` instead of `IF SET`.
8. Use short aliases for tables and views.
9. Name variables in `SELECT` statement, then it will be clear what goes where.
Have I forgot something?

**Logic/Design**.
1. Instead of multiple variables you could use temp table variable or just temp table. It would make code shorter and more readable.
2. First `SELECT` returns one row, but in the `INSERT` statement you might insert something completely irrelevant.
3. Having the same data in two tables might be a sign of bad design.
4. Having Date and Datetime for the same event in the same row is very suspicious.

It might be as the code below. Hope that helps.

```
DECLARE @Coid INT;
DECLARE @DTRID INT;
DECLARE @EMPID INT;
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME;
DECLARE @PAIR INT;
DECLARE @TIMEOUT DATETIME;

DECLARE @IdentityValue TABLE ( 
    ContactID int,
    EmpId int, 
    ContactDate DATETIME
);

-- Select ONLY one row
SELECT TOP 1 
    @EMPID = e.Id, 
    @Coid = e.CompanyId, 
    @DATE = tr.TimeIn, 
    @DTRID = tr.Id,
    @TIMEOUT = GETDATE(),
    @PAIR = CASE WHEN tr.TimeIn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM tblEmployees as e
INNER JOIN tblDailyTimeRecord as tr
    ON e.Id = tr.EmployeeId 
WHERE tr.Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
    AND tr.TimeOut IS NULL 
ORDER BY tr.ID DESC;

IF @Coid IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- Insert more than one row or might insert nothing
    INSERT INTO [tblDailyTimeRecord] (
        [EmployeeId],
        [Date],
        [TimeOut],
        [IsModified],
        [CompanyId]
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, 
            INSERTED.EmployeeId, 
            INSERTED.TimeOut 
        INTO @IdentityValue
    SELECT Id as [EmployeeId], 
        CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) as [Date],
        @TIMEOUT as [TimeOut],
        0 as [IsModified],
        CompanyId 
    FROM tblEmployees 
    WHERE AccessCode = 'GI0056';

    INSERT INTO tblTimeLog(
        [EmployeeId],
        [Time],
        [Type],
        [TimeLogSourceId],
        [CreationDate])
    SELECT EmpId as [EmployeeId],
        ContactDate as [Time],
        2 as [Type],
        11 as [TimeLogSourceId],
        @TIMEOUT as [CreationDate]
    FROM @IdentityValue;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE [tblDailyTimeRecord] 
    SET TimeOut = @TIMEOUT, 
        PairNo = @PAIR 
    WHERE ID = @DTRID

    INSERT INTO tblTimeLog(
        [EmployeeId],
        [Time],
        [Type],
        [TimeLogSourceId],
        [CreationDate]
    ) VALUES (
        @EMPID, 
        @TIMEOUT,
        2,
        11,
        @TIMEOUT
    );
END
```

Comment: Thank you Slava for your explanation.